# Compile error during unpacking variadic pack in recursive function

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

Lets have following code which creates a tree of tuples and n-ary operator to aggregate values on particular level:

```
#include <tuple>

template<class O, class... I>
struct Compose
{
    using ITuple = std::tuple<I...>;

    Compose(O&& o, I&&... i) :
        o(std::forward<O>(o)),
        i(std::forward<I>(i)...)
    { }

    float operator ()(float x) const
    { /* return o(i1(x), i2(x), i3(x), ... ); */ }

    template<unsigned H1, unsigned H2, unsigned... Ts>
    decltype(auto) getI()
    { return std::get<H1>(i).getI<H2, Ts...>(); }

    template<unsigned H>
    decltype(auto) getI()
    { return std::get<H>(i); }

    O o;
    ITuple i;
};

template<class O, class... I>
Compose<O, I...>
make_compose(O&& o, I&&... i)
{ return Compose<O, I...>(std::forward<O>(o), std::forward<I>(i)...); }

struct Foo {
    Foo(float param) : p(param) { }

    float operator()(float v) const
    { return p * v; }

    float p;
};

int main()
{
    auto out = [](float x, float y) { return x + y; };
    auto c1 = make_compose(out, make_compose(out, Foo(2), Foo(3)), Foo(4));
    auto test1 = c1.getI<0, 1>();
    test1(1); // will return 3
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with -std=C++14 and when i use GCC 6.4 it compiles fine. But with clang++ 3.9 it fails with error:

> error: expression contains unexpanded parameter pack '`Ts`'
>   `{ return std::get<H1>(i).getI<H2, Ts...>(); }`

Does anybody knows where is the real problem, beacuse it looks for me as obvious expansion of variadic parameter pack. Method `getI()` returns element in the tree by index on that level of tree.

I have found workaround for method `getI<>()` which passes the tuple element into a helper function `doGetI()` works in clang but looks messy:

```
template<unsigned... Ts>
decltype(auto) getI()
{ return doGetI<Compose2, Ts...>(*this); }

template<class T, unsigned H1, unsigned H2, unsigned... Ts>
decltype(auto) doGetI(T& t)
{ return doGetI<std::tuple_element_t<H1, typename T::ITuple>, H2, Ts...>(std::get<H1>(t._i)); }

template<class T, unsigned H>
decltype(auto) doGetI(T& t)
{ return std::get<H>(t._i); }
```

Comment: `std::get<H1>(i).template getI<H2, Ts...>();`

Comment: Heh far too easy to solve, difficult to ask on google such specific problem. I wish to be C++ for the humans not machines :S .